# Dependency Injection - What is the best approach?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

**Scenario**

Talk about Symfony2. I have an entity with his setters and getters. One of this setter is a bit particular, because have to retrieve some related object, do something and write back ralationship. 
What came in my mind, for retrieve those objects, is to use the entity manager and repository related to my entity.

**Problem**

I haven't the possibility to access Entity Manager directly from entity. One possible solution is to inject the E.M. into this entity but, as far I know, dependency injection is not recommended for entity.

**Possible solution**

Write a service, inject into it E.M., use service into entity.
**Please pay attention to this**: I can't instantiate my entity elsewhere because a Bundle (SonataAdmin) is responsible for doin' that.

Is this a good way to do it, or exists a better method?

Comment: Is creating a real relationship between your entities an option? In this case you could easily access the related entity.

Comment: @m0c I can't understand what you're saying...

Comment: If you just want to get entity A within Entity B, I would create a relation with @ORM\OneToOne or something similar. Or do you want to retrieve another "object", which does not represent an entity?

Comment: I would retrieve the other object

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're working with the Entity 1. You need to get entity 2.

I would create a service, with a function which get Entity 1 as a parameter. Give E.M. to this service, and get Entity 2.

Entity file isn't made to such a thing, services are here to help you.

Comment: I agree - you don't want put any service into your entities

Comment: @Gmajoulet: Yes I know that and as I say previously .... Is exactly what I said. Take a look to comment that I gave to Cyprian. 
I would like to know if my idea was good...

Comment: yep but you write also "Write a service, inject into it E.M., use service into entity.". You don't want use service inside an entity. Instead of that a better idea is (like @Gmajoulet said) use service and pass entity into it (in that way you never use any service inside an entity)

Comment: Looks like you have your answer. :) Yes, this is a very good way to do this.